# Get diff between two arrays of objects with ES6 or TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following arrays:

```
  arr1 = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Diego',
      age: 23
  }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Brian',
      age: 18
  }]

  arr2 = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Diego',
      age: 23
  }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Brian',
      age: 18
  }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Pikachu',
      age: 88
  }]
```

I need get difference between this two arrays, the espected result is:

```
arr3 [{id:3, name: 'Pikachu', age: 88}]
```

How do i solve this problem using `ES6` or `TypeScript`?

I tried using [SET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), but doesn't worked.

Comment: First, write or find a routine to take the difference of two sets, based on some equality function. Then, write the equality function for your case.

Comment: I thought about it, but im was looking for a simpler way. I will do as you said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
let ids1 = arr1.map(item => item.id);
let ids2 = arr2.map(item => item.id);

let diff = ids1.map((id, index) => {
        if (ids2.indexOf(id) < 0) {
            return arr1[index];
        }
    }).concat(ids2.map((id, index) => {
        if (ids1.indexOf(id) < 0) {
            return arr2[index];
        }
    })).filter(item => item != undefined);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20arr1%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Diego'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%2023%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Brian'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%2018%0D%0A%20%20%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20arr2%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Diego'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%2023%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Brian'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%2018%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Pikachu'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%2088%0D%0A%20%20%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0Alet%20ids1%20%3D%20arr1.map(item%20%3D%3E%20item.id)%3B%0D%0Alet%20ids2%20%3D%20arr2.map(item%20%3D%3E%20item.id)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20diff%20%3D%20ids1.map((id%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(ids2.indexOf(id)%20%3C%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20arr1%5Bindex%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D).concat(ids2.map((id%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(ids1.indexOf(id)%20%3C%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20arr2%5Bindex%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D)).filter(item%20%3D%3E%20item%20!%3D%20undefined)%3B))